# Don't destroy Vue-Cookies on browser or tab close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies

I am using [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) in my **Vue App.** I am storing cookie as:

```
$cookies.set('authUser', authUserObj);
```

> Here `authUserObj` is the object containing my `access_token`

But if I close the tab and reopen it I am being redirected to login page, then I checked cookies there's no cookies in the browser, any suggestions?
The expiry time is also 1 day:

[image]

Comment: May be it's a bug or what now it's working, I cleared cache but not worked but now it's working (Don't know why but it works :D)

Comment: It's weird. Are you using Incognito mode? Check your code see whether you accidentally delete the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You should set expire time

```
// 1 day expire time
$cookies.set('authUser', authUserObj, '1d');
```

Otherwise, it will be treated as session cookie and will be erased when browser closes.

Comment: Bro it's 1 day by default. I have double checked it. Check I have added image in my question.